# How to load bulk data to table from table using query as quick as possible? (postgresql)

Tags: postgresql, select, insert, copy

I have a large table(`postgre_a`) which has 0.1 billion records with 100 columns. I want to duplicate this data into the same table.

I tried to do this using sql

`INSERT INTO postgre_a select i1 + 100000000, i2, ... FROM postgre_a;`

However, this query is running more than 10 hours now... so I want to do this more faster. I tried to do this with `copy`, but I cannot find the way to use `copy from` statement with query.

Is there any other method can do this faster?

Comment: Did you drop all indexes and constraints before the operation?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Yes. There is only Primary key constraints. Do I have to drop primary key also?

Comment: If you want good performance, yes.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Thanks. btw, Do you know any other methods/queries such as using `COPY` to do this faster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot directly use a query in `COPY FROM`, but maybe you can use `COPY FROM PROGRAM` with a query to do what you want:

```
COPY postgre_a
FROM PROGRAM '/usr/pgsql-10/bin/psql -d test'
             ' -c ''copy (SELECT i1+ 100000000, i2, ... FROM postgre_a) TO STDOUT''';
```

(Of course you have to replace the path to `psql` and the database name with your values.)

I am not sure if that is faster than using `INSERT`, but it is worth a try.

You should definitely drop *all* indexes and constraints before the operation and recreate them afterwards.